# what is probability that there will be a shortage of the product, and probability of having a shortage is less than 3%

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

In a store, when the quantity of any product falls below $20$ units, the order for new products is made. It is assumed that the product order has a normal distribution with an average of $15$ and a standard deviation of $6$.

$a)$ Determine the probability that there will be a shortage of the product, ie determine the probability $P (X> 20)$.

$b)$ Determine the number of products, so that the probability of having a shortage is less than 3%.

My attemp is: we make the transition of variable $X(15,6)$ to the variable $Y$
$$Y=\frac{X-15}{6}$$

for par $a)$ 
$$P (X> 20)=P(\frac{X-15}{6}>\frac{20-15}{6})=P(Y>0.83)=1-P(Y<0.83)=1-F_Y(0.83)=\cdots$$

I don't know if this part is good, and I don't know how to calculate it $F_Y(0.83)=???$

For part $b)$
$$P(X<x)=0.03$$
Through the variable Y we do the transition
$$Y=\frac{X-15}{6}$$
$$P(X<x)=P(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})=F_Y\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}=0.03$$
$$F_Y(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})=0.03/^{-1}$$
$$(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})=F_Y^{-1}(0.03)$$
$$x=\mu+\sigma F_Y^{-1}(0.03) $$
$$x=15+6\cdot ?$$
I don't know if this part is good, and I don't know how to calculate it $F_Y^{-1}(0.03)=???$

Please help me. Thanks for your attetnion and your help.

Comment: StubbornAtom can you help me

Comment: This problem is missing context and details. I see formulas, but no definitions. What does the random variable $X$ represent? Why does $P(X>20)$ indicate the probability of a shortage? Is $X$ the number of units purchased? What is the starting stock?